# zshconfig command is not found

Tags: server

I'm unable to perform `zshconfig`.  Ubuntu is not recognizing the command.

The problem I'm having is I'm trying to set up a server on Ubuntu.  My apache is up and running; I checked by typing in `localhost` in my browser and it brought up my apache page.  But when I went to `/var/hosts` and added `test.dev`, the browser didn't recognize it even though I saved it in the correct file.

I then was told Linux Valet would help me solve this problem.  So, I'm currently trying to install that but now in a part of [the Linux Valet tutorial](https://youtu.be/l1ZX0ZLxRps?t=286) `zshconfig` is used to change a path, and my system is not recognizing that command, and now I'm stuck.

I'm very very new to this so I apologize if some of this doesn't make sense.

I've included time stamped links to help show where I'm stuck...

[You Tube tutorial I'm using on setting up Apache on Ubuntu](https://youtu.be/TrLAx27Npns?t=417)

sub `/etc/hosts`

`test.dev` not working even though added so I think tried to add Linux Valet, but now I can’t use `zshconfig`.

can’t perform zshconfig

Comment: `zshconfig` isn't a command found in the Ubuntu software repositiories. After `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate` runs, `locate zshconfig` will find the file. You may want to append the directory containing `zshconfig` to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the user in the tutorial has made an [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) called `zshconfig` for a command like `nano ~/.zshrc`, because your video shows them opening their shell config file in the text editor `nano` and editing it to add to their PATH.

You are probably using Bash, not Zsh (ignore this if you ARE using Zsh), so instead of `zshconfig`, you can simply use the command `nano .bashrc`, and whenever the user in the video refers to `.zshrc`, you can replace `.zshrc` with `.bashrc` or the full path `~/.bashrc`.

I don't know what Linux Valet is or whether it will solve your problem, but this should get you over the current hurdle.